# Close pop up by pressing anywhere on the screen

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to close the pop-up by trying to simulate a click on the body of the web page. It is possible to locate the close button and close it. However, I am trying to close the pop-up as there can be 1-3 pop-ups in some pages and all can be closed with a single click on the body. (easier to automate) Is there a way to simulate a body click to close that pop-up.

I have tried :

```
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()
 driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div').click()
 driver.execute_script("document.getElementByTagName('body').click()")
```

None of them seem to work. All were performed by a sleeping thread and/or even an implicit wait

Url of page: https://www.mryum.com/sookthaikitchen/pickup/main-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because these elements don't receive the click.

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').click()
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('div').click()
```

Assuming your case, you want to get rid of this pop-up, the best approach would be to handle this pop-up like this.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "Thanks!")]').click()
```

Otherwise, you can always use [ActionChains](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/action-chains-in-selenium-python/)

Apparent approach if pop-ups are dynamic

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
action = ActionChains(driver=driver) # your current chrome / Firefox driver
x = action.move_by_offset(100, 100).click()
x.perform()
```

Comment: Yes I can close the pop ups with the close button or the thanks button, but these pop ups are dynamic. The page can contain multiple pop ups or not include those types of buttons as described in the question. Any other way to simulalate a click on the body

Comment: I have added some edits, check if that fits in.

Comment: Yes this work perfectly. Seems like it does a right click. Is there an argument for left? Nevertheless it works fine.

Comment: Instead of `context_click()` use `click()`

Answer (score 0):

It will be good answer in your case.

> #### pip install autoit

```
import ait
ait.move(100, 100) //(x, y) is random point which does not contain button or a tag
ait.click()
```

Comment: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'XK' I got an issue with ait. Any other solution? seems like it Is not available for mac?

Comment: File "/Users/aadesh/Desktop/resscraper/scrape_rest.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ait
  File "/Users/aadesh/Desktop/resscraper/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ait/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .ait import *
  File "/Users/aadesh/Desktop/resscraper/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ait/ait.py", line 57, in <module>
    from . import _linux as _mod
  File "/Users/aadesh/Desktop/resscraper/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ait/_linux.py", line 9, in <module>
    class KeyEvent:

Comment: File "/Users/aadesh/Desktop/resscraper/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ait/logger.py", line 192, in KeyEvent
    for name in dir(Xlib.XK)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'XK'
@top talent